# How to handle long tap on ListView item?

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I catch such event? `onCreateContextMenu` is quite similiar, but I don't need menu.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's hard to know what you need to achieve. But my guess is that you want to perform some acion over the item that receives the long click. For that, you have two options:

- add an [AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html). See [setOnItemLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29).

.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //do your stuff here
  }
});
```

- if you are creating a custom adapter, add a [View.OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) when creating the View in the method [Adapter#getView(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Comment: could you please clarify how to assign OnItemLongClickListener to my ListView? Thank you in advance.

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly. How can I get particular database value, associated with the item long clicked? Should be something like `this.getListAdapter().getItem(position)`?

Comment: @LA_ `T obj = (T) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: thanks it wrks fine.. :) :) :) :) was trying both with onclick listview & lonclick listview.. was able to do onclik but not onlongclick.. now i can do both on listview :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 14):

Normally, you'd associate a long click on a list view with a context menu, which you can do by registering the listView with `Activity.registerForContextMenu(View view)` to give a more consistent user interface experience with other android apps.

and then override the onContextItemSelected method in your app like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.menu_context_title));
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.some_item:
        // do something useful
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The position in the list is also held in `info.id`

If you just want to capture the long click event, then I think what Snicolas is suggesting would work.

Comment: it doesn't work. Looks like because I don't have context menu - onContextItemSelected is never called.

Comment: I've updated the code example. Did you call `registerForContextMenu(listView)`? As others have said, are you trying to achieve something when the item is long clicked or are you trying to get a context menu up for the item on your list view?

Comment: I am trying to start another activity, when the item is long clicked. So, no need to show context menu. `RegisterForContextMenu(listView)` is there.

Comment: Ok, i've added the `onCreateContextMenu()` code for completeness in the snippet, but as you don't want to use context menus, it's probably not the way you want to go. Though I would strongly suggest you still use them for long clicks on list items, and maybe show "start ...", as it will allow the user to hit the Back button if they accidentally held the button too long.

If you want the longclick, then go with one of the other suggestions here about adding a new listener to the view.

Comment: One more thing: As I was in an Fragment I needed to call "getActivity().getMenuInflater();" not only "getMenuInflater();"

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom View.OnLongClickListener to your views. It can be shared by many instances, then you can use the parameter of

```
onLongClick(View v)
```

to know which view has been clicked and react accordingly.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Would this mess up the ListView's normal scroll/fling functionality?

Comment: Strange, but it doesn't work also. I do: `public class BridgesCloseActivity extends ListActivity {  ... OnLongClickListener longClickListener;  ...         longClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {
         public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          Log.i("", Integer.toString(v.getId()));
          return true;
         }
        };`

Comment: @LA_ You may need to have onDown return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Deleted individual cart items
    //on list view cell long press
    cartItemList.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() {
          @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
              final CharSequence[] items = { "Delete" };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                builder.setTitle("Action:");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        cart = cartList.get(position);
                        db.removeProductFromCart(context, cart);

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.success))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.item_removed))
                        .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CartDetailsActivity.this, HomeScreen.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                         })
                         .show();

                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            //do your stuff here
              return false;
          }
        });
```